# How get a reference to a GoogleMap object created in java?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, object

I'm trying to get a reference to a GoogleMap object created java, and i don't know how to get this reference.

Here's my code:

```
        LinearLayout mapLayout = new LinearLayout(customToursActivity);
        mapLayout.setId(generateViewId(rootView));
        int mapLayoutHeight = Math.round(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_tour_list_map_size));
        mapLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mapLayoutHeight));
        layout.addView(mapLayout);

        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =  SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(mapLayout.getId(), supportMapFragment).commit();
        GoogleMap mMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Here's the log i got:

```
01-23 17:09:54.168    3795-3795/abff.googlemapsappteste E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: abff.googlemapsappteste, PID: 3795
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at abff.googlemapsappteste.CustomToursList.createPlacemarksList(CustomToursList.java:458)
            at abff.googlemapsappteste.CustomToursList.onCreateView(CustomToursList.java:73)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2618)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2019)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1177)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1383)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1065)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5901)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do the same.

**1).** If you are targeting an application after API level 12, then you can simply make use of `MapFragment` instead of `SupportMapFragment`. Below is the sample code how you can add `MapFragment` to your `Fragment` and get reference to `GoogleMap` Object.

```
 Map mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
         getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(mapLayout.getId(), mapFragment).commit();
```

Then use `getMapAsync()` to set the callback on the fragment.

```
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); // your fragment need to implement `OnMapReadyCallback`
```

> Note: getMapAsync() must be called from the main thread, and the
>   callback will be executed in the main thread. If Google Play services
>   is not installed on the user's device, the callback will not be
>   triggered until the user installs Play services.

Use the `onMapReady(GoogleMap)` callback method to get a handle to the GoogleMap object. The callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used. It provides a non-null instance of GoogleMap. You can use the GoogleMap object to set the view options for the map or add a marker, for example.

```
    @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
      map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

you can refer official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map)

**2).** But if you are targeting an application earlier than API level 12 or you still want to use `SupportMapFragment` for some reason, you can further have two otpions.

**a).** Since the map initialization is async, you have to wait for `SupportMapFragment.onCreateView()` to be called which is basically after your Fragment `onActivityCreated()` and before `onStart()`. So  if you add `SupportMapFragment` to transaction inside `onActivityCreated()` then you will have `getMap()` returning object in `onStart()` or `onResume()` (unless of course Google Play Services is not available). Below is the code sample.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_with_map, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        mSupportMapFragment =  SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(mapLayout.getId(),mSupportMapFragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleMap == null) {
            mGoogleMap = mSupportMapFragment.getMap();
        }
    }
}
```

If you face any `IllegalStateException`(an issue tracked in Google Bugs) just `Override` your Fragment `onDetach()`

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    try {
        Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class
                .getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
        childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
        childFragmentManager.set(this, null);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

**b).** You can `Override` the `onActivityCreated()` of the `SupportMapFragment`. For example.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

        private SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment;
        private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_with_map, container, false);
    mSupportMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            mGoogleMap = mSupportMapFragment.getMap();
            if (mGoogleMap != null) {
               mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    };
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(mapLayout.getId(), mSupportMapFragment).commit();;
    return view;   
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me alot.

Answer (score 1):

Since map initialization is async in current Play Services, I guess you call the getter before the GoogleMap object was set in the Fragment. You could use a custom Callback to be notified when the GoogleMap is ready, or you can use an event bus like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/).